# ASp.net webform with Update Panel doesnt trigger Save Button event

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, updatepanel

My client side validation works fine with Validation summary until  i don't add `onclientclick="ClientSideClick(this)"`to button.

I tried to add trigger also their but it still doesn't work neither validation is triggered not form is submitted.

Not sure why or what change needed to make it work.

If i removed this code from button `onclientclick="ClientSideClick(this)"` then it works fine but i need to trigger validation using JS so that user doesn't submit same form multiple times.

I have removed other form element from the page so that it is easy to understand.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="SiteMain.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ArticleDetails.aspx.cs" Inherits="ArticleDetails" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <!--- Code -HERE -->
            <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">

                   <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" CssClass="validation-sum" ValidationGroup="vgCommentForm" />

                <div class="cmt-fullname-w">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtcmtFullName" placeholder="Full Name" runat="server" CssClass="txt-cmt-fn" TabIndex="1"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Name can't be blank" CssClass="dp-cmt-validation" ControlToValidate="txtcmtFullName" ValidationGroup="vgCommentForm"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </div>

                <div class="cmt-email-w">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtcmtEmail" placeholder="Email" runat="server" CssClass="txt-cmt-fn" TabIndex="1"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Email can't be blank" ControlToValidate="txtcmtEmail" CssClass="dp-cmt-validation" ValidationGroup="vgCommentForm"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Enter correct email" ControlToValidate="txtcmtEmail" CssClass="dp-cmt-validation" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" ValidationGroup="vgCommentForm"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                </div>

                <div class="cmt-btnsave-w">
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CssClass="buttonPopups" OnClick="btnSaveComments_Click" OnClientClick="ClientSideClick(this)" Text="Post Comment" ValidationGroup="vgCommentForm" CausesValidation="true" UseSubmitBehavior="False" />
                </div>
            </asp:Panel>
            <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Visible="false" CssClass="comment-pnl-success-w">
                <div class="comment-success">Successfully submitted</div>
            </asp:Panel>
            <!--- Code -HERE -->
        </ContentTemplate>
        <%--                            <Triggers>
                                <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSaveComments" />
                            </Triggers>--%>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <!--- UpdatePanel -->




    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function () {

            $("#dp-trans-comment").click(function () {
                $('#commentModel').modal('show');
            });


            //Avoid Multiple Submission
            function ClientSideClick(myButton) {
                // Client side validation
                if (typeof (Page_ClientValidate) == 'function') {
                    if (Page_ClientValidate("vgCommentForm") == false) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                //make sure the button is not of type "submit" but "button"
                if (myButton.getAttribute('type') == 'button') {
                    // diable the button
                    myButton.disabled = true;
                    myButton.className = "btn btn-inactive";
                    myButton.value = "Please Wait..";
                }
                return true;
            }


        });

    </script>

</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested your code. It gave `ClientSideClick is not defined` in the browser console. That's because the function is nested in another one. Move it outside `$(window).load(function () {`. After that the validation worked and the method is triggered in the update panel.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function () {
        $("#dp-trans-comment").click(function () {
            $('#commentModel').modal('show');
        });
    });

    //Avoid Multiple Submission
    function ClientSideClick(myButton) {
        // Client side validation
        if (typeof (Page_ClientValidate) == 'function') {
            if (Page_ClientValidate("vgCommentForm") == false) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        //make sure the button is not of type "submit" but "button"
        if (myButton.getAttribute('type') == 'button') {
            // diable the button
            myButton.disabled = true;
            myButton.className = "btn btn-inactive";
            myButton.value = "Please Wait..";
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

Update

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        bindcommentModel();
    });

    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

    //this is triggered at updatepanel update, so rebind the button again
    prm.add_endRequest(function () {
        bindcommentModel();
    });

    function bindcommentModel() {
        $("#dp-trans-comment").click(function () {
            $('#commentModel').modal('show');
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Perfect, Thanks. So you mean to function somehow doesn bind due to this

Comment: Yes, a function within a function cannot be found. Also If `commentModel` is inside the UpdatePanel, you need to rebind that also when the updatepanel is triggered. I will add this to my answer

Comment: This is really helpful